# Receive error "version `GLIBCXX_3.4.23' not found" while trying to reactivate Matlab License

Tags: software-installation, matlab, glibc

I am trying to reactivate my license for Matlab and I am getting stuck because I cannot click on a link.

Here is the link that I cannot click on:
[image]

When I do try to click on the link, I get this error output on the console:

> Gtk-Message: 14:48:26.448: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>   XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so:
>   /home/kobe/Matlab/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.23' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so)
>   Couldn't load XPCOM.

But when I run the following:

> strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

GLIBCXX_3.4.23 does appear.

What gives?